# Qt QWizard validateCurrentPage isn't called on last page

Tags: c++, qt, qwizard

I have a QWizard, and I override validateCurrentPage() in order to perform actions before passing to the next page.
This function is working well on all pages, except for the last page - where Finish is pressed.
the accept() function is called, but not validateCurrentPage().

Judging by Qt docs:

> This virtual function is called by QWizard when the user clicks Next or Finish to perform some last-minute validation

this function was supposed to be called just like in any other page.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: It might be that the function signature is incorrect.

Comment: virtual bool validateCurrentPage() override;

Also I mentioned that it works for all the pages except for the last one.. so signature should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I overridden QDialog::accept() and unless I call QDialog::accept(), validateCurrentPage() wouldn't be called.